# conditional compilation in makefile so that command-line arguments are ignored

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, arguments, conditional-statements

Using gcc compiler on linux, I have a C program that used command-line argument (one argument) like
./myprog 0

I want to write a makefile that uses conditional compilation so that if I compile like
make SPECIAL=1
then command-line argument is used.
if I compile without SPECIAL like
make
then command-line argument is ignored even if we enter it.

How to make it possible.
I am using following compilation command
gcc -o myprog myprog.c prog2.c prog3.c

Answer (score 0):

The makefile can be trivial but the real work has to happen in the C code. Something like this, as a minimal example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
  int i;
 #ifndef SPECIAL
  argc=1;
  argv[1] = NULL;
 #endif
  for(i=1; i<argc; ++i) {
    printf(">>%s<<\n", argv[i]);
  }
}
```

Now, you don't even really need a `Makefile` for this simple program.

```sh
bash$ make CFLAGS=-DSPECIAL=1 -f /dev/null myprog
cc -DSPECIAL=1     myprog.c   -o myprog
```

Having said that, making your build nondeterministic by introducing variations which depend on ephemeral build-time whims is a recipe for insanity. Have two separate targets which create two separate binaries, one with the regular behavior, and the other with the foot-gun semantics.

```
DEPS := myprog.c prog2.c prog3.c # or whatever your dependencies are

myprog: $(DEPS)

myprog-footgun: CLAGS+=-DSPECIAL=1
myprog-footgun: $(DEPS) # same dependencies, different output file
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

See [Target-specific Variable Values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) in the GNU Make documentation for details of this syntax.

(Notice that Stack Overflow renders tabs in the Markdown source as spaces, so you will not be able to copy/paste this verbatim.)

I would perhaps in fact reverse the meaning of `SPECIAL` so that it enables the foot-gun version, rather than the other way around (the original version of this answer had this design, just because I had read your question that way originally).

Comment: The explicit recipe for `myprog-footgun` is probably too simple for real use (it lacks library paths, etc). A workaround on systems which have symlinks is to `ln -s myprog.c myprog-footgun.c` and then just let `make` run its default recipe (though then you'll need to change `DEPS` slightly, too).